# Hide and reShow Panels/components in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

[Initial Panels Position - image](http://s10.postimg.org/faysrw1sp/question.png)

Hi, im trying to make one button action that do the following behaviour:

1) when i first click the button1 the panel1 will dissapear and the panel2 will get the size of Parent container.

2) If i reclick the button the panel1 will appear again and the panel2 will rezise.

Then problem is on step 2, when i reclick the button1 the panel2 dont resize well and get, somehow fixed values (check: [problem - image](http://s3.postimg.org/uyn5w9bgz/question2.png)).

i was trying something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        if (panel1.Visible){
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel1.Enabled = false;         
            panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
        else{
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel1.Enabled = true;
            panel2.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            panel2.Anchor = ((AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom) | AnchorStyles.Left) | AnchorStyles.Right;
        }

    }
```

PS: Check the image link, might help to understand the problem. Also the panel2 in my project is a WebBrowser component.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the control you should probably be using is the SplitContainer control.

You can use Panel1 of the SplitContainer as your first Panel as-is, and in Panel2 of the SplitContainer, you would Dock-Fill your WebBrowser control.

If the panels aren't supposed to be resized by the user, then set

```
splitContainer1.IsSplitterFixed = true;
```

To hide the first Panel, all you would call is:

```
splitContainer1.Panel1Collapsed = true;
```

You obviously set it to false to bring it back.

Comment: Not exactly what i wanted to do but solved my problem with panel2 not resizing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Before you run, copy the location of the panel1 and repost it to the same location. Example

```
  if (panel1.Visible){
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel1.Enabled = false;         
            panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
        else{
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel1.Enabled = true;
            panel2.Dock = DockStyle.None;
            panel2.Location = new Point(15, 15);
            panel2.Height= //Original height before you run.
            panel2.Anchor = ((AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom) | AnchorStyles.Left) | AnchorStyles.Right;
        }
```

Note : new Point will hold the location before you run. Also try add the same height and width . I think that might work. I am thinking this change in location is due to the dock property used and just undocking might not be sufficient.

**Update on TableLayoutPanel**

When i have complex cntrols that requires changes dynamically. In that case, i suggest using TAbleLayoutPanel. You can put your panels in a table layout, and dock the table in where ever you want. You caan dock the panels inside the table also. Then you can hidde, dock and undock and your panel will be in a fix grid, because its in a a table. Check TableLayoutPanel [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) or better a TableLAyoutPanel on youtube. Hope this help.

Comment: I tryed before your solution, the problem is i will never know the width and height of the panel2 since its resizing automaticaly depending of the size of MainForm (i.e.: if i have the windows maximized or with a random size). This way i can not save the original values because they are not constant.

Comment: Hi, use tableLayoutPAnel in that case. See my update above. Put your panels in a a taleLayoutpane(i.e) a grid. Then dock the TAble and it will always take the shape you want.

Comment: Hi. Definitely a good solution. To be honest i was unaware of this component. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

use the `splitcontainer` control and add both panel control in its panle1 and panel2.

by clicking on button set `splitcontainer1.panle1.visible = true` and `splitcontainer1.panle2.visible=false` and next click `splitcontainer1.panle1.visible = false` and `splitcontainer1.panle2.visible=true`